# Can someone give me an example JavaScript RegEx to invalidate 2 repeating characters from being entered

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, passwords, validation

I need a RegEx to trigger a validation message when a user enters 2 repeating characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well

```
var repeats = /(.)\1/;
```

will match any string with a character repeated in it.

Thus

```
if (repeats.test("hello")) alert("true because of the two 'l' characters");
```

and

```
if (!repeats.test("frederick the great")) alert("test fails because no characters repeat");
```